# Running a JMeter test with multiple users with the same number of transactions over different time period

Tags: jmeter

in Visual Studio Load testing there is an option in the test mix to set a value for each specific test to be run by all the users assigned to that scenario a specific number of times. Therefore if you want to increase the load by increasing the number of times a transaction is executed in a test you can increase the user load or set the number of times a particular transaction is run. This facility also spaces out each time a transaction is run, so that the transaction is run throughtout the test.
With Jmeter if I want to achieve a similar affect I would need to change the value of the ConstantTimer (I think) for each new user load.

Example:
Test time 300 sec, Transaction count required = 20, Thread Count =1, Constantimer =15 secs
Test time 300 sec, Transaction count required = 20, Thread Count =5, Constantimer =75 secs

Is the ConstantTimer the correct timer to use (with a loop obviously) for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a specific number of requests per unit of time, i.e. 20 transactions in 300 seconds the most obvious choice is using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)

20 transactions in 300 seconds is 4 transactions per minute and given you configure the Constant Throughput Timer like this:

[image]

you will "tell" JMeter to pause its requests to 4 transactions per minute no matter how many threads you have.

A more flexible option is using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) and [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) combination, this way you will not be only able to pause threads to limit JMeter's throughput to the given number of requests per minute, but also kick off new threads if current amount is not sufficient to reach/maintain the target throughput.